# Modify a Fib script to encounter sessions

Tags: session, fibonacci, pine-script

[Drawing/explenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdNfh.jpg) I need to make the following script (© TradeChartist) adjust according to the session "1700-1700", I am not sure how to put in the time formula in a correct way.. It is set up to using daily, but that is not solving my problem...

2 second need is to adjust to two sessions if 61,8 is crossed by more then 15 pips.

First issue is most pressing though...

Help would be most appreciated.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © TradeChartist

//@version=4
study("Fib Retracement", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000)


Fibs            = input("Plot Fibs based on Lookback", options = ["Plot Fibs based on Lookback", "Plot Fibs based on Price Input"], title = "Fibonacci Plot Type")

FIBS            = Fibs == "Plot Fibs based on Lookback"?1:Fibs == "Plot Fibs based on Price Input"?2:na

Foption         = input(defval = "1. Candles" , title = "Fibonacci Plot Lookback Type", options=["2. Days", "1. Candles"]) 
FP              = input(defval =     100 , title = "Days/Candles to Lookback") 
Reverse         = input(defval =  false , title = "Reverse Fibonacci Levels?")
ExtraFibs       = input(false, "Show 0.886 and 1.113 Fibs")


Note            = input(true, "════      ════")
High            = input(0., minval = 0,  title = "High - Enter Value")
Low             = input(-1., minval = -1, title = "Low - Enter Value")


Note2           = input(true, "══════  /  ══════")
Bull_Color      = input(#008000, type=input.color, title = "Support Fibs Color")
Bear_Color      = input(#ff0000, type=input.color, title = "Resistance Fibs Color")
CurrentFib      = input(false, "Show Fib Level of Current Price")
Current_Color   = input(color.orange, type=input.color, title = "Current Fib Label Color")
LineStyle       = input("Dotted", options = ["Dotted", "Solid"], title = "Fib Line Style")
LineWidth       = input(1, minval=1, maxval=3,title = "Fib Line Width")
Ext             = input(false, "Extend Lines Left")


// Transparency = input("Low", options = ["High", "Medium", "Low"], title="Fib Line Transparency")



BullColor       = Bull_Color//Transparency == "High"?color.new(#008000,75):Transparency == "Medium"?color.new(#008000,50):Bull_Color
BearColor       = Bear_Color//Transparency == "High"?color.new(#ff0000,75):Transparency == "Medium"?color.new(#ff0000,50):Bear_Color


FPeriod         = timeframe.isintraday and Foption=="2. Days"? (1440/timeframe.multiplier)*FP: 
                     timeframe.isdaily and Foption=="2. Days"? FP/timeframe.multiplier: 
                     timeframe.isweekly and Foption=="2. Days"? FP/(7*timeframe.multiplier): 
                     timeframe.ismonthly and Foption=="2. Days"? FP/(28*timeframe.multiplier): 
                     Foption=="1. Candles"? FP:100

 
Fhigh           = FIBS==1? highest(FPeriod) : FIBS == 2 and High == 0? highest(high,100): FIBS == 2 and High!=0? High:na
Flow            = FIBS==1? lowest(FPeriod) : FIBS == 2 and Low == -1? lowest(low,100): FIBS == 2 and High!=-1? Low:na
FH              = FIBS == 1?highestbars(high,FPeriod): 1
FL              = FIBS == 1?lowestbars(low,FPeriod): 2
revfibs         = not Reverse? FL>FH : FL<FH



Fib_x(n) =>
    revfibs ? (Fhigh-Flow)*n+Flow : Fhigh-(Fhigh-Flow)*n

Current         = revfibs?(close-Flow)/(Fhigh-Flow):(Fhigh-close)/(Fhigh-Flow)

var label Current_Fib_Label = na
label.delete(Current_Fib_Label)

if(CurrentFib and barstate.islast)
    Current_Fib_Label := label.new(bar_index, close, tostring(Current, "##.##"), textcolor = Current_Color, color = color.new(#000000,100), style=label.style_label_left, yloc=yloc.price)




EXTEND          = Ext?extend.left:extend.none 
STYLE           = LineStyle=="Dotted"?line.style_dotted:line.style_solid
WIDTH           = LineWidth

BB = FIBS==1?(FL<FH?bar_index[-FL]:bar_index[-FH]):FIBS==2?bar_index[50]:bar_index[50]

Fib_line(x)  => 
    var line ln = na
    line.delete(ln)
    ln:=line.new(BB, x, bar_index, x, color = close>x? BullColor:BearColor, extend=EXTEND ,style=STYLE, width = WIDTH)
    

    
Fib_label(x,_txt) => 
    var label lbl = na
    label.delete(lbl)
    lbl:=label.new(bar_index, x, _txt + tostring(x, "##.########") + " )", textcolor = close>x?BullColor:BearColor, color = color.new(#000000,100), style=label.style_label_left, yloc=yloc.price)



Fib0        =    Fib_line(Fib_x(0))
Fib236      =    Fib_line(Fib_x(0.236))
Fib382      =    Fib_line(Fib_x(0.382))
Fib500      =    Fib_line(Fib_x(0.500))
Fib618      =    Fib_line(Fib_x(0.618))
Fib786      =    Fib_line(Fib_x(0.786))
Fib1000     =    Fib_line(Fib_x(1.000))

Fib886      =    ExtraFibs?Fib_line(Fib_x(0.886)):na

if(FIBS==2)

    Fib1113 =   ExtraFibs?Fib_line(Fib_x(1.113)):na    
    
    Fib1272 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(1.272))
    Fib1618 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(1.618))
    Fib2000 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(2.000))
    Fib2236 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(2.236))
    Fib2618 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(2.618))
    Fib3236 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(3.236))
    Fib3618 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(3.618))
    Fib4236 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(4.236))
    Fib4618 =   Fib_line(Fib_x(4.618))
    

LFib0       =      Fib_label(Fib_x(0), "0 ( ")
LFib236     =      Fib_label(Fib_x(0.236), "0.236 ( ")
LFib382     =      Fib_label(Fib_x(0.382), "0.382 ( ")
LFib500     =      Fib_label(Fib_x(0.500), "0.500 ( ")
LFib618     =      Fib_label(Fib_x(0.618), "0.618 ( ")
LFib786     =      Fib_label(Fib_x(0.786), "0.786 ( ")
LFib1000    =      Fib_label(Fib_x(1.000), "1.000 ( ")

LFib886     =      ExtraFibs?Fib_label(Fib_x(0.886), "0.886 ( "):na


if(FIBS==2)

    LFib1113 =      ExtraFibs?Fib_label(Fib_x(1.113), "1.113 ( "):na   
    
    LFib1272 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(1.272), "1.272 ( ")
    LFib1618 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(1.618), "1.618 ( ")
    LFib2000 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(2.000), "2.000 ( ")
    LFib2236 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(2.236), "2.236 ( ")
    LFib2618 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(2.618), "2.618 ( ")
    LFib3236 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(3.236), "3.236 ( ")
    LFib3618 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(3.618), "3.618 ( ")
    LFib4236 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(4.236), "4.236 ( ")
    LFib4618 =      Fib_label(Fib_x(4.618), "4.618 ( ")
```

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you want the script to do. Could you edit your question and add some extra explanation please? Possibly with some screenshots that show what you're looking for?

Comment: Sure, I would like to add the possibility of choosing session from "1700-1700" so that it is choosing high/low and drawing fib in the session... I guess I need something like this in there, but not sure how to put it in: "t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t"   to the script

Comment: 1700 to 1700. So you want to draw the fibs 24/7 in each session? It would be helpful if you could draw what you want manually on a chart, so we can see what you mean.

Comment: I would like to draw fib in the latest session, but if price crosses 61,8 (with10 pips or more) I would like it to include high low in current + previous session.

Comment: Which `high/low` is used for the fib in your drawing on 12/11 and what's the lookback period for that fib? Also, suppose a new session starts and there are only 5 bars yet in that new session, which `high/low` should be used to draw the fib in that new session?

Comment: Yes, you do have a fair point, thanks for sharing your thoughts!
The method I want to follow is concerned with Natural Gas, it has a way of revisiting its daily fib levels (high low within 1700-1700 UTC), a break below/above 61,8 will confirm up/down move. This is typically happening between 6-10 UTC, hence for this exact issue it might not be a big issue. But it will look funny… Hence a rule to make it more smooth could be to include 4 extra hours until 2100 where it is only including from 1700 (1700-4, 1800-4, 1900-4, 2000-4). Please tell me if it is still unclear!

Comment: an example could be today the dec contract made a high/low like shown here https://www.tradingview.com/x/GuZUc9cV/ , then the 1st point of interest is to see if it will be bought up or if it will go down, also the previous session has a interesting info https://www.tradingview.com/x/aVh9I2Ct/ as you see it was not able to break above 61,8 from previous session, upside is in other words not yet confirmed. a perfect way to see this would be like this : https://www.tradingview.com/x/R9R4MgBS/

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you define a session as 1700-1700 UTC. Then you want to draw a fib in the current session, using the `high/low` of the previous session. Then, when it breaks the 61.8 level, you want to redraw the fibs, using the `max(high) min(low)` counted from the start of the previous session, up until the time of the 61.8 level break. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly correct ! I think it also important that if it is breaking it by 10 pips it should not redraw, the break has to be larger...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created this:

```
//@version=4
study("Fib Retracement", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000)

var int     sessionStartHour = input(17,    "Session start hour (UTC)",   input.integer)
var bool    extendLeft       = input(false, "Fib line extend left",       input.bool)
var bool    extendRight      = input(false, "Fib line extend right",      input.bool)
var float   fibBreakLevel    = input(61.80, "Fib break level",            input.float)
var int     fibBreakDistance = input(10,    "Level break distance (ticks)", input.integer)

var float   fibBreakLevelPrice = na
var string  extendType       = extendLeft and extendRight ? extend.both : extendRight ? extend.right :  extendLeft ? extend.left : extend.none
var float   curSessionHi     = na
var float   curSessionLo     = na
var float   prevSessionHi    = na
var float   prevSessionLo    = na
var int     curHour          = na
var int     curBarIndexHi    = na
var int     curBarIndexLo    = na
var int     prevBarIndexHi   = na
var int     prevBarIndexLo   = na
var int     fibLevelCount    = na
var bool    lowFirst         = na
var int     fibStartBar      = na
var         arrFibLevels     = array.new_float()
var         arrFibColors     = array.new_color()
var bool    levelBroken      = na

var l0 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l1 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l2 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l3 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l4 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l5 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l6 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l7 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l8 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var l9 = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)

f_moveLine(_id, _x, _y, _color) =>
    line.set_xy1(_id, _x, _y)
    line.set_xy2(_id, bar_index, _y)
    line.set_color(_id, _color)

fib_setLevels() =>
    array.clear(arrFibLevels)
    array.push(arrFibLevels,  00.00), array.push(arrFibColors, color.green)
    array.push(arrFibLevels,  23.60), array.push(arrFibColors, color.blue)
    array.push(arrFibLevels,  38.20), array.push(arrFibColors, color.blue)
    array.push(arrFibLevels,  50.00), array.push(arrFibColors, color.blue)
    array.push(arrFibLevels,  61.80), array.push(arrFibColors, color.yellow)
    array.push(arrFibLevels,  78.60), array.push(arrFibColors, color.blue)
    array.push(arrFibLevels, 100.00), array.push(arrFibColors, color.red)
    array.size(arrFibLevels)

fib_retrace(_startBar, _levelLo, _levelHi, _lowFirst) => 
    var float level0   = na
    var float level    = na
    var line  ln       = na
    var int   dir      = na
    var color fibColor = na
    var float breakPrice = na
    var float fibLevel = na

    dir := _lowFirst ? 1 : -1
    fibRange = abs(_levelHi - _levelLo)
    level0 := _lowFirst ? _levelLo : _levelHi
    
    for i = 0 to fibLevelCount-1
        ln       := i==0 ? l0 : i==1 ? l1 : i==2 ? l2 : i==3 ? l3 : i==4 ? l4 : i==5 ? l5 : i==6 ? l6 : i==7 ? l7 : i==8 ? l8 : i==9 ? l9 : na
        fibLevel := array.get(arrFibLevels, i)
        level    := level0 + (dir * fibRange * fibLevel/100)
        
        if (fibLevel == fibBreakLevel)
            breakPrice := level
        
        fibColor := array.get(arrFibColors, i)
        f_moveLine(ln, _startBar, level, fibColor)
        
    breakPrice

if barstate.isfirst
    fibLevelCount := fib_setLevels()
    
curHour := hour(time, 'UTC')
newSession = (curHour == sessionStartHour) and change(curHour)

if newSession

    prevSessionHi  := curSessionHi
    prevSessionLo  := curSessionLo
    prevBarIndexHi := curBarIndexHi
    prevBarIndexLo := curBarIndexLo

    lowFirst       := prevBarIndexLo < prevBarIndexHi
    fibStartBar    := lowFirst ? prevBarIndexLo : prevBarIndexHi

    curSessionLo   := na
    curSessionHi   := na
    curBarIndexHi  := na
    curBarIndexLo  := na
    levelBroken    := na

// Draw fibs for prev session
fibBreakLevelPrice := fib_retrace(fibStartBar, prevSessionLo, prevSessionHi, lowFirst)

if lowFirst
    levelBroken := close > (fibBreakLevelPrice + (fibBreakDistance * syminfo.mintick))
else    
    levelBroken := close < (fibBreakLevelPrice - (fibBreakDistance * syminfo.mintick))

curSessionHi  := max(high, nz(curSessionHi))
curSessionLo  := min(low,  nz(curSessionLo, 1.0e23))
curBarIndexHi := change(curSessionHi) ? bar_index : curBarIndexHi
curBarIndexLo := change(curSessionLo) ? bar_index : curBarIndexLo

if levelBroken
    prevSessionHi  := max(prevSessionHi, curSessionHi)
    prevSessionLo  := min(prevSessionLo, curSessionLo)

// Debug section
// plotchar(prevSessionLo, "prevSessionLo", "")
// plotchar(prevSessionHi, "prevSessionHi", "")
// plotchar(prevBarIndexLo, "prevBarIndexLo", "")
// plotchar(prevBarIndexHi, "prevBarIndexHi", "")
// plotchar(curBarIndexLo, "curBarIndexLo", "")
// plotchar(curBarIndexHi, "curBarIndexHi", "")
// plotchar(lowFirst, "lowFirst", "")
// plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "")
// plotchar(fibStartBar, "fibStartBar", "")
// plotchar(fibBreakLevelPrice, "fibBreakLevelPrice", "")
// plotchar(levelBroken, "levelBroken", "")

bgcolor(newSession ? color.yellow : na)
```

Update 02 dec 2020:
This is the solution I have up until now.
It seems to work mostly, but it'll probably still contain some bugs.
Let me know if you find something wrong.

```
//@version=4
study("Fib retr 4", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000)
// study("Fib retr 4", overlay=true)

// ======== INPUTS ========
// {
var bool    i_extend_left           = input(false,  "Fib line extend left",     input.bool)
var bool    i_extend_right          = input(false,  "Fib line extend right",    input.bool)
var float   i_fib_break_level       = input(61.80,  "Fib break level",          input.float)
var float   i_fib_break_margin      = input(00.00,  "Fib break margin",         input.float)
// } === END INPUTS ===

// ======== VARIABLES ========
// {
var bool    newSession              = na
var string  extendType              = i_extend_left and i_extend_right ? extend.both : i_extend_right ? extend.right :  i_extend_left ? extend.left : extend.none
var int     sessionsBack            = 0
var int     max_keep_sessions       = 100

var float[] arr_fib_levels          = array.new_float()
var color[] arr_fib_colors          = array.new_color()
var float[] arr_fib_draw_coords     = array.new_float() // (x1, y1, x2, y2)

var line    l0                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l1                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l2                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l3                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l4                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l5                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l6                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l7                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l8                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)
var line    l9                      = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, extend=extendType)

var float   fibLevelToBreak         = na
var bool    fibLevelBroken          = na

var int[] arrNewSessionBars = array.new_int(na)
var int barsBack = na

// } === END VARIABLES ===

// ========= FUNCTIONS =========
// {
f_move_horizontal_line(_line_id, _bar_start, _level, _bar_stop, _color) =>
// {
    line.set_xy1(_line_id, _bar_start, _level)
    line.set_xy2(_line_id, _bar_stop,  _level)
    line.set_color(_line_id, _color)
// }

// Initializes fibonacci levels and colors.
f_fib_init_levels(_arr_fib_levels, _arr_fib_colors) =>
// {
    array.clear(_arr_fib_levels)
    array.push(_arr_fib_levels,  00.00), array.push(_arr_fib_colors, color.green)
    // array.push(_arr_fib_levels,  23.60), array.push(_arr_fib_colors, color.blue)
    // array.push(_arr_fib_levels,  38.20), array.push(_arr_fib_colors, color.blue)
    // array.push(_arr_fib_levels,  50.00), array.push(_arr_fib_colors, color.blue)
    array.push(_arr_fib_levels,  61.80), array.push(_arr_fib_colors, color.yellow)
    // array.push(_arr_fib_levels,  78.60), array.push(_arr_fib_colors, color.blue)
    array.push(_arr_fib_levels, 100.00), array.push(_arr_fib_colors, color.red)
// }

// Retrieves the direction of the fibonacci retracement for the given coords (point1, point2)
f_fib_get_direction_for_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) => (_y1 < _y2) ? -1 : (_y1 > _y2) ? 1 : 0

// Retrieves the zero level of the fibonacci retracement for the given coords (point1, point2)
f_fib_get_level_zero_for_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) => _y2

// Retrieves specifications from a fibonacci retracement for the given coords (point1, point2)
f_fib_get_specs_for_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) =>
// {
    fib_range       = abs(_y1 - _y2)
    fib_direction   = f_fib_get_direction_for_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2)
    fib_level_zero  = f_fib_get_level_zero_for_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2)
    [fib_range, fib_direction, fib_level_zero]
// }

// Draws a fibonacci retracement with given coordinates.
f_fib_draw_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2, _x_stop) =>
// {
    // Fib is drawn from point1 to point2. Point1 = 100%-level, Point2 = 0%-level.
    var int fib_linecount = array.size(arr_fib_levels)

    if not fib_linecount
        f_fib_init_levels(arr_fib_levels, arr_fib_colors)
        fib_linecount := array.size(arr_fib_levels)

    [fib_range, fib_direction, fib_level_zero] = f_fib_get_specs_for_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2)
    
    fib_x_start     = min(_x1, _x2)
    fib_x_stop      = max(max(_x1, _x2), nz(_x_stop) ? _x_stop : bar_index)
    
    for i = 0 to fib_linecount-1
        fib_line    = i==0 ? l0 : i==1 ? l1 : i==2 ? l2 : i==3 ? l3 : i==4 ? l4 : i==5 ? l5 : i==6 ? l6 : i==7 ? l7 : i==8 ? l8 : i==9 ? l9 : na
        fib_level   = fib_level_zero + (fib_direction * fib_range * array.get(arr_fib_levels, i) / 100)
        fib_color   = array.get(arr_fib_colors, i)
        f_move_horizontal_line(fib_line, fib_x_start, fib_level, fib_x_stop, fib_color)
// }

// Retrieves the value of the requested fib level for the given coords (point1, point2)
f_fib_get_level_value_for_coords(_requested_fib_level, _x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) =>
// {
    [fib_range, fib_direction, fib_level_zero] = f_fib_get_specs_for_coords(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2)
    fib_level = fib_level_zero + (fib_direction * fib_range * _requested_fib_level/100)
// }

// f_getHiLoCoords(_sessionsBack) =>
f_getHiLoCoords(_len) =>
    lo      = lowest(_len)
    hi      = highest(_len)
    bar_lo  = bar_index + lowestbars(_len)
    bar_hi  = bar_index + highestbars(_len)
    if bar_lo < bar_hi
        [bar_lo, lo, bar_hi, hi]
    else
        [bar_hi, hi, bar_lo, lo]

f_setFibDrawCoords(_barsBack) =>
    [x1, y1, x2, y2] = f_getHiLoCoords(_barsBack)
    array.clear(arr_fib_draw_coords)
    array.push(arr_fib_draw_coords, x1), array.push(arr_fib_draw_coords, y1)
    array.push(arr_fib_draw_coords, x2), array.push(arr_fib_draw_coords, y2)

f_getFibDrawCoords() =>
    x1 = int(array.get(arr_fib_draw_coords, 0)), y1 = array.get(arr_fib_draw_coords, 1)
    x2 = int(array.get(arr_fib_draw_coords, 2)), y2 = array.get(arr_fib_draw_coords, 3)
    [x1, y1, x2, y2]

f_fib_draw(_x_stop) =>
    [x1, y1, x2, y2] = f_getFibDrawCoords()
    f_fib_draw_coords(x1, y1, x2, y2, _x_stop)
    
f_fib_get_level_value(_level) =>
    [x1, y1, x2, y2] = f_getFibDrawCoords()
    f_fib_get_level_value_for_coords(_level, x1, y1, x2, y2)

f_get_bars_back(_sessionsBack) =>
    arrSize = array.size(arrNewSessionBars)
    result = bar_index - (arrSize > 0 ? array.get(arrNewSessionBars, min(_sessionsBack, arrSize ? arrSize-1 : 0)) : bar_index) + 1 // number of bars to look back for high/low
// } ==== END FUNCTIONS ====


// ======== MAIN ========
// {
newSession  := change(time("D"))

if newSession
    array.unshift(arrNewSessionBars, bar_index) // Most recent addition always at index 0
    if array.size(arrNewSessionBars) > max_keep_sessions
        array.pop(arrNewSessionBars) // remove last element
    sessionsBack := 0

f_setFibDrawCoords(f_get_bars_back(sessionsBack))

fibLevelToBreak := f_fib_get_level_value(i_fib_break_level)
fibLevelBroken  := cross(close, fibLevelToBreak - i_fib_break_margin) or cross(close, fibLevelToBreak + i_fib_break_margin)

if fibLevelBroken
    sessionsBack := sessionsBack + 1
    
f_fib_draw(bar_index)

// } === END MAIN ===

// ======== DEBUG ========
// {
// plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "")
// plotchar(myFibLevel64, "myFibLevel64", "")
// plotchar(myFibLevelBroken, "myFibLevelBroken", "")
// plotchar(barsBack, "barsBack", "")
// plot(myFibLevel64)
// bgcolor(newSession ? color.white : na, 70)
// } === END DEBUG ===
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224603/discussion-on-answer-by-bjorn-mistiaen-modify-a-fib-script-to-encounter-sessions).